# WorkerPool example from LMAX Disruptor framework

Tags: lmax

Looking for a WorkerPool example from LMAX Disruptor Framework. The idea is to use it when we want to make sure that event is only consumed once ( Pollable Channel rather than subscribable Channel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didnt read the whole LMAX documentation and examples :-). Here are some of the examples i could find ( these use Disruptor DSL but the concept is pretty much same) 
https://github.com/LMAX-Exchange/disruptor/blob/master/src/test/java/com/lmax/disruptor/dsl/DisruptorTest.java#L337